# Delphi : [int] in [array] operation is not working

Tags: delphi

I have a boolean that needs to be set if a number is present within a certain array. I would like to check for it by doing this :

```
procedure test();
var
    arr: Array[0..255] of smallint;
    i: smallint;
begin
    arr[0] := 1;
    i := 1;
    if i in arr then
        writeln('IN')
    else
        writeln('OUT')
end;
```

Running this will get the error : *E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type*.
But I'm seeing this approach in a lot of stackoverflow answers. Which does this particular implementation not work ? I am missing a compiler directive ?
I'm on Delphi 10.3 (Rio).

Comment: Link to a couple of those answers. Or pay attention to their details, because `in` does not work on everything.

Comment: I don't know why Embarcadero publish IndexStr and not IndexInt method. Then, you use Delphi 10.3, not Delphi 7, check how to use TList it will be easier to get value with (IndexOf), sort, add, delete, ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected.

[The `in` operator](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Set_Operators) is used with [sets](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets), not [arrays](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Arrays).

If you need to check if an array contains a particular value, you need to iterate over the array in the standard way:

```pascal
function MyArrayContains(const AArray: array of SmallInt;
  const AValue: SmallInt): Boolean;
begin
  for var i := Low(AArray) to High(AArray) do
    if AArray[i] = AValue then
      Exit(True);
  Result := False;
end;
```

Using advanced record types and [operator overloading](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)), you can, however, define your own array-based record type with `in` operator support.

Comment: If you change the function to take an open array as parameter, then you can pass in static and dynamic arrays of any length. As shown, the function only works with the specific static array that is declared.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, in this example an open array parameter is better.